# Ramification group of valuations - need terminology

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, valuation-theory

I am lost and need some terminology (also hopefully sources).
Let $L/K$ be a Galois extension, and $w$ be a valuation of a $L$, lying above a valuation $v$ of $K$. Notice that I do not suppose that $w$ is discrete.
Given $\alpha >0$ in the finite image of $w$, each of the following can easily been shown to be a subgroup of the inertia group of $w$ in $L$ :

- $\{ \sigma\in Gal(L/K) : w(\sigma x - x) \geq \alpha \}$,
- $\{ \sigma\in Gal(L/K) : w(\sigma x - x) > \alpha \}$,
- $\{ \sigma\in Gal(L/K) : w(\sigma x - x) \geq w(x) + \alpha \}$,
- $\{ \sigma\in Gal(L/K) : w(\sigma x - x) > w(x) + \alpha \}$.

What is the terminology for these subgroups ? (I guess some variant of "ramification group of order $\alpha$) ? 
Can you indicate me a source ?
Thx.

Comment: When the valuations are discrete and $L/K$ is an extension of local fields, the first two groups you indicated are called "higher ramification groups".

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not help me because I do not suppose the valuations are discrete, which is all the point (since the two first groups are allegedly not of the same kind in general).